# mysql query to update data in table using 2 tables

Tags: mysql

i am trying to build a simple cms system. I have 2 tables:

table pages:

```
id  |   index   |   lang
-------------------------------
1   |   9       |   1
2   |   10      |   1
3   |   11      |   1
4   |   0       |   2
5   |   0       |   2
6   |   0       |   2
```

table pairs:

```
id1 |   id2
------------
1   |   4
2   |   5
3   |   6
```

What i'm trying to do, is to update the index in pages which have lang=2 to the same number that have lang=1 and are their paired pages according to the other table.

In the above example i need to update pages 4,5,6 and set their indexes to 9,10,11

Is it possible to do this in 1 query? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this with a multi-table update:

```
UPDATE pages AS l2
INNER JOIN pairs AS p ON l2.id = p.id2
INNER JOIN pages AS l1 ON l1.id = p.id1
SET l2.index = l1.index
WHERE l2.lang = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE pages
SET index = (SELECT id1 FROM pairs WHERE pages.id = pairs.id2)
WHERE updateTbl.index = 0
```

(Edited; misread the question)

Comment: ok, i see. so whats the simplest solution to do this correctly? thanks.

Comment: I changed the WHERE part to pages.language = 2, but id didnt work correctly